# Add colour outline to section of image map when clicked (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image map with four sections, and in essence I want to:

1. When a section is clicked, add a colour outline to the selected section.
2. When a new section is clicked, remove outline from previous chosen section, and add the colour outline to the new section.

This is what I've tried:

In the style block I included

```
.act{
    outline: purple solid thick;
}
```

Then, the jQuery,

```
$('area').click(function(){

            choice = $(this).attr('alt');
            $('#choice').html(choice);
            $(this).addClass('act');

        });
```

In mind mind, the last line would add the class "act" but would not remove the class when a new section is clicked. Again, in my mind, $(this).siblings().removeClass('act'); should do that trick???
 Finally, the html,

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">

        <div class = "col-md-8">

            <img src="plate1.jpg" width="800" height="618" border="0" usemap="#map" />

            <map name="map">
                <area shape="rect" coords="58,26,373,274" alt="1"  nohref="nohref" />
                <area shape="rect" coords="427,28,742,272" alt="2"  nohref="nohref" />
                <area shape="rect" coords="60,325,380,571" alt="3"  nohref="nohref" />
                <area shape="rect" coords="426,325,747,571" alt="4"  nohref="nohref" />
            </map>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you all for your contributions.
Best regards,

Comment: share your example somewhere

Comment: why dont you change the `addClass` to `toggleClass` within your jQuery?

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work...

Comment: Are you comfortable with `Plugins`? I think there is not any direct way to do this with only JS/HTML/CSS - You can use SVG.

Comment: Not really. Would you be able to refer me to any relevant example?

Comment: @capitombolare Here it is a Plugin - http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/ Refer it. and have tried to resolve your problem with only HTML/CSS/JS but its not working, maybe I'm unable to reach at Problem. But it will Help you.

Comment: is it possible to add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @capitombolare
Here it is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hardy_411/djra3gov/), you can check it.

Comment: Another Plugin is [jQuery maphilight](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/)

Comment: @HP's 411 Um... interesting. I get the same problem in your jsFiddle. As in my application your code reveals the number of the section clicked, but no outline appears... I've tried with Chrome and Firefox...

Comment: @capitombolare : have tried a lot, but not having much time to solve this. for now it is better way to Use **Plugins**

Comment: @HP's 411. It's ok. Regarding maphilight, it almost does what I need, but not quite. This selects the area when mouse passes over, but the area does not remain selected when clicked.

Comment: @capitombolare : check [this] (http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_features.html). It hase what you need. It is from **Map Hilight**

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you.

[Reference](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some investigation, I managed to solve the problem -thanks to HP's 411 for his suggestion on plug-ins.

The relevant code to do this is (with maphighlight) is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.map').maphilight({

        fillColor: '00ff00',
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
        neverOn: true
    });

    $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps(); // Used to resize image maps.


    $('area').click(function() {
        choice = $(this).attr('alt');
        $('#choice').text(choice);

        var data = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
        data.alwaysOn = true;
        $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');;

    }); });
```

You have to add the plugins `jquery.maphilight.js` and `jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js`.
In the HTML,

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-8">

        <img id="someid" src="image.jpg" width="800" height="618" border="0" usemap="#map"/>

        <map name="map">
            <area shape="rect" coords="58,26,373,274" alt="1" href="#"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="427,28,742,272" alt="2" href="#"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="60,325,380,571" alt="3" href="#"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="426,325,747,571" alt="4" href="#"/>
        </map>

    </div>
</div>
```